# Как выбрать и заблокировать 100 строк?

Tags: sql, oracle

Несколько потоков модифицируют таблицу. Хочу выбрать из таблицы 100 не заблокированных строк и заблокировать их. Написал запрос:

```
select * from table where rownum <= 100 for update skip locked
```

Однако при таком варианте сначала применяется условие `rownum<=100` и только потом выбрасываются заблокированные строки из результата запроса. Обернуть этот запрос не разрешается. Как можно выбрать первые 100 не заблокированных строк из таблицы и заблокировать их ?

Comment: Как то по данным из инета все грустно, люди в основном предпочитают оракловые курсоры использовать. Теоретически конечно можно курсор обернуть в функцию, которая по одной строке будет возвращать через pipe row и использовать такую функцию в качестве источника данных в from

Comment: Это нагруженная система, потому и хочется обойтись 1 запросом. Но похоже, что так нельзя (

Comment: Как Mike советует, заверните в pipelined, практически это будет один запрос  и довольно шустрый. Или выберите другие критерии для ограничения, не обязательно же именно 100 rows.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, pipelined приведет к большому количеству переключений контекста плюс мне надо ровно 100 строк.

Comment: Нет, pipelined  обеспечивает паралеьное выполнение.  Для SQL контекста всё что функция возвращает как результат, это тот же row source, как и обычная таблица или  GTT. В ней 100 строк и реализуете без труда.

Comment: С pipelined погорячился немного, всё хорошо, но только не с DML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Существующее ограничения на `for update` не позволяют решить эту задачу только средствами SQL. В подзапросе этот конструкт недопустим, в 12c `fetch first n rows only` тоже не совместим с `for update`, т.е. такое не выполнится:

```
select * from (select * from table for update skip locked) where rownum <= 100;
```

Завернуть в табличную функцию также проблематично, так как она не может содержать DML операции, если её вызывать в запросе.

Исключение - автономные трансакции, но есть слабое место - выбранные строки между возвратом и основным запросом будут разлочены, что может привести к нежелательному результату. Следующий пример вроде решает задачу, но краш-тест с несколькими потоками в цикле без сомнения выявит недостатки:

```
create or replace type itemRow as object (id number,  name varchar2 (32));
/
create or replace type itemRows  is table of itemRow;
/
drop table items; 
create table items (id number,  name varchar2 (32));
/
insert into items 
select level, 'item '||level from dual connect by level<=200
;
create or replace function getUnlockedItemsBlock return itemRows is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
    cursor mycur is 
        select itemRow(i.id, i.name) item from items i for update skip locked;
    ret itemRows;
begin 
    open mycur;
    fetch mycur bulk collect into ret limit 100;
    close mycur;
    commit;
    return ret;
end;
/
update items set name=name||'*' where id between 5 and 104; 

100 rows updated.
```

В другой сессии:

```
select i.id, i.name, count (1) over () "total locked by myself" 
from items i 
join table (getUnlockedItemsBlock) t on t.id = i.id
for update of i.id
;


    ID NAME                             total locked by myself
------ -------------------------------- ----------------------
     1 item 1                                              100
     2 item 2                                              100
     3 item 3                                              100
     4 item 4                                              100
   105 item 105                                            100
   106 item 106                                            100
   107 item 107                                            100
   108 item 108                                            100
   ...
```

Наиболее приемлиемое решение - надо, или отказаться от `for update skip locked` для разделения "зон влияния" между потоками, или как минимум от идеи "только одним SQL запросом" и остаться в PL/SQL контексте:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
<<processUnlockedItemBlock>> declare
    cursor mycur is 
        select itemRow(i.id, i.name) item from items i for update skip locked;
        items itemRows;
begin 
    open mycur;
    fetch mycur bulk collect into items limit 100;
    close mycur;
    for idx in 1..items.count loop 
        dbms_output.put_line ('processing item: '||items(idx).id||'/'||items(idx).name); 
    end loop; 
end;
/

processing item: 1/item 1
processing item: 2/item 2
processing item: 3/item 3
processing item: 4/item 4
processing item: 105/item 105
processing item: 106/item 106
processing item: 107/item 107
processing item: 108/item 108
... /* всего 100 строк */
```

Также приемлимо завернуть подобный курсор в функцию возврающую результат в виде массива залоченых строк в клиент для дальнейшей обработки и завершения трансакции.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, могу просто не делать `commit` внутри функции, и тогда строки останутся заблокированы так, как я хочу ?

Comment: Если бы было так просто я бы его тоже не сделал. Это подзапрос, и в нём недопускаются открытые трансакции.  Получите `ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back`

Comment: Хм. Похоже, можно пойти несколько другим путем. Можно все нужные данные так же через курсор заблокировать и дальше внутри того же блока выполнить нужные мне преобразования. В понедельник проверю

Comment: Ну да, вот это "Обернуть этот запрос не разрешается" мешает. Почему не разрешается?

Comment: Я хотел обойтись одним `SQL`. А наприсать `select * from (select * from table for update)` нельзя

Comment: Нет, так нельзя, та же проблема - подзапрос.   `for update` допускается только в основном запросе.

Comment: Задача решается  просто, или как в примере, берёте 100 строк и обрабатываете не выходя, или возвращаете эти же 100 строк как массив клиенту для дальнейшей обработки. В обоих случаях,  `autonomous_transaction` не нужна.

Comment: Сейчас оно примерно так и работает, только про `bulk collect .. limit 100` забыли, и строчки блокируются по одной и заносятся в массив.